# How to apply cosine_similarity to my dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have a dataset:

```
     0   1   2    3  ... n
0   0.7 0.1 0.55 0.8 ...0.7
1   0.4 0.8 0.5  0.1 ...0.1
...........................
n-2 0.1 0.1 0.5  0.5 ...0.2
n-1 0.2 0.2 0.2  0.1 ...0.4
n   0.1 0.1 0.1  0.4 ...0.7
```

it has shape nxn

I want to apply sklearns cosine_similarity : `from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity`

but when i do `cosine_similarity(df, dense_output = False)` I get error:

`Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')`

Comment: From error message it seems like we have few invalid values in dataframe. 
Can you check by removing each column from the dataframe?
or start with 1 or 2 columns.. and then slowly include each column and try `cosine_similarity`.
By this way, we can identify the column(s) which cause error.. then find the value in the error?

Or try to get max, min values, NaN values count of each columns.
We may get some insight